# Check if series is timedelta

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, timedelta

I'd like to transform a Pandas series in case its dtype is `np.timedelta64`. Is there any way I can check the type of the series? `series.dtype == np.timedelta64` does not work. I could check the first element (`isinstance(first_element, np.timedelta64)`) or use the `series.dtype.name`, but thought there must be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I think you have to stick to your current method `inferred_type` is an attribute of `Index` objects not `Series`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [3]: s = Series(pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5),unit='s'))

In [4]: s
Out[4]:
0   00:00:00
1   00:00:01
2   00:00:02
3   00:00:03
4   00:00:04
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [6]: s.dtype == 'timedelta64[ns]'
Out[6]: True

In [10]: s.dtype == 'm8[ns]'
Out[10]: True

# select_dtypes is only defined on frames
# this is generally the most robust method
In [11]: s.to_frame().select_dtypes(include=['timedelta'])
Out[11]:
         0
0 00:00:00
1 00:00:01
2 00:00:02
3 00:00:03
4 00:00:04

In [12]: from pandas.core.common import is_timedelta64_dtype

In [13]: is_timedelta64_dtype(s.dtype)
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: `pandas.core.common.is_timedelta64_dtype` is now found in `pd.api.types.is_timedelta64_dtype`.